# Why is my cursor on the wrong line after NextLine()?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
    String word; 
    System.out.println ("Please type hello");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
    word = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println ("Okay");    
}
```

I have a problem with nextLine() method and it is that when I type a word on a keyboard, I want the cursor of the keyboard to be on the next line of "Okay".
However, it is on the same line as "Okay".

Can you please let me know how I can move the cursor to the next line it as I've been on this for 2 hours and couldn't find any solutions?

Thanks in advance.

I tried to find solutions for this problem but all of them are related to nextInt(), which I haven't used in this code.
Also I tried to use "\n" but it didn't solve anything.

Comment: @Arnaud, tried that as well, but the cursor is still on the "Okay"

Comment: Cursor of the keyword? you have to read other value from the input? Can you please decribe your problem and if possible attach the screenshot of what exactly you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are using the simulated console in your IDE (Eclipse or something) to test-run your program, right? Is this what happens?

[image: Eclipse Console Screenshot]

The simple answer is: This doesn't work like a real terminal. While you can just type even if the cursor is in the "wrong" line and the input text will appear in the "correct" line, it doesn't create a perfect illusion of a proper terminal.

Export your program to a runnable `.jar` file and run it on your systems terminal/console with `java -jar yourProgramName.jar` and you will be happy!

Comment: Thank you so much. It actually solved my problem :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. And it's an uplifting answer, too ;) It means your program actually works exactly as expected, you just run it in an "improvised" environment.

Answer (score 1):

Did you missed a `System.out.println`?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
    String word; 
    System.out.println ("Please type hello");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
    word = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println (word); // << missed line
    System.out.println ("Okay");    
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. It's already `System.out.println("Okay");`. The problem is that in the Eclipse console (and probably other IDE consoles), the cursor position is handled differently than on a real command line.